# Facebook iOS SDK 3.1 does not return to the app after authentication

Tags: ios, facebook

I'm using Facebook iOS SDK 3.1 and it does not return to my app after authentication. I'm sure the bundle ID has been entered and the login and deep link has been enabled since last night. Anyone know the possible reason or has the same problem?

Thanks,

Comment: Could you post the code showing which method you're using to invoke the auth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you added these two functions. Also check your product name matched your facebook app name. Use 'URL types' in plist.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
    Facebook *fb = [self sharedFacebook];    
return [fb handleOpenURL:url];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
    Facebook *fb = [self sharedFacebook];    
    return [fb handleOpenURL:url];
}
```